# In $ABC$, if $a^4-2(b^2+c^2)a^2+b^4+b^2c^2+c^4=0$, then find angle $A$

Tags: trigonometry

$$\sin^4A-2(\sin^2A+\sin^2C)\sin^2A+\sin^4B+\sin^2B\sin^2C+\sin^4C=0$$

$$\implies \sin^4A+\sin^4B+\sin^4C+2\sin^2B\sin^2C-2\sin^2A\sin^2B-2\sin^2A\sin^2C-\sin^2B\sin^2C=0$$

$$\implies (\sin^2A-\sin^2B-\sin^2C)^2=\sin^2B\sin^2C$$

How do I proceed from here?

Comment: You're missing the exponent $2$ on the left side...Anyways, take the square root, revert back to side lengths and try to see if the Cosine formula helps...

Answer (score 1):

$$\cos A = \frac{b^2 + c^2 - a^2}{2bc}$$

Now, $$(b^2 + c^2 - a^2)^2 = b^4 + c^4 + a^4 +2(b^2c^2 -a^2(b^2 + c^2))
\\
\implies (b^2 + c^2 - a^2)^2 = b^2c^2$$

Hence $\cos A = \pm \frac{1}{2}$

Answer (score 0):

$$(b^2+c^2-a^2)^2=(bc)^2$$

$$\implies b^2+c^2-a^2=\pm bc$$

$$\implies\cos A=\pm\dfrac12$$